# Update an already deployed custom action

Tags: 2010, ribbon, custom-actions

How can I modify the CommandAction associated with a CommandUIHandler that has already been deployed and activated through a feature?

I need to change the javascript code that gets executed when the related ribbon button is clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update same solution and then deploy updated WSP file to server. That's it.